# Is this a checkmate for White?

Tags: rules, checkmate, stalemate

```
[FEN "8/3RkQ2/3B4/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

**Is there a way out for Black?**

 My son and I finished this way (only the relevant parts of the position are shown in the diagram), but reading about stalemates now has us confused. We are new to the game and I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: My position might be controversial, but I would argue that this is not mate as the rules have not been followed. Instead, the position is meaningless, and the moves should be reversed back to the point the rules were broken, and the game should then be resumed from there. This is what I would do if I were instructing two players.

Comment: @AaronHall That's a wise viewpoint. Technically, if this happened in a tournament game under FIDE rules, if both players signed the scoresheet, the game is over and the result is final. But, of course, this isn't a tournament game but a friendly game and a learning experience.

Comment: I assume noth are you are just playing for fun. If it were a blitz game it can make sense to miss checks.. but this idk how you got here...

Comment: In blitz games under FIDE rules, illegal moves are not retracted if they are not immediately noticed (if they are noticed, the player who made the illegal move loses), so this position can occur. So technically it is a good, meaningful question to ask whether this position is a mate, and the answer to that question does not depend on whether this position can be achieved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be checkmate, because the king is in check and has no valid move to escape. But it's impossible to get into this position if you follow normal chess rules. The most you can do is a double-check (using a discovered attack), but your position shows a triple-check.

The stalemate rule is only applicable when the king is not in check, so it doesn't apply here.

Comment: I agree. Can you post the last few moves?

Comment: Even if you take away any one of white's pieces, the position still could not arise. For example, take away the bishop and think about what white's move must have been, it could either be a queen move or a rook move. In either case black was in check at the beginning of white's move, which can not happen. All valid double checks involve a discovery, but all three checks here are contact checks and so they can't be discoveries.

Comment: There is also no white king, so we are all assuming that it's somewhere irrelevant on the board. If it was adjacent to the black king that would be another problem.

Comment: @R.T.: It's clear from [the questioner's photo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cpCrV.jpg) that the kings were not adjacent. (Someone has since replaced the photo with a diagram that doesn't distinguish between definitely empty squares and squares that were merely out of view in the photo.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not checkmate, since it's not possible to get in this position.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick question.  Technically the chess board is invalid.  Where is the white King?  Still, this is a check mated position.  This is the second check mated position

Answer (score -1):

Here is explanation about Discovered Check:
Discovered check happens when one piece moved and after moving that piece the attack of anther piece touches the king it is discovered check.

Discovered Check could be happend and result maximum 2 checks Suppose an empty Chess board and if my enemy's black king on E file on E8 square and my white rook is on E1 and white bishop is on E2 then if i move my white bishop to H5 square now note the situation
My bishop is attacking from H5 square to my enemy king
My rook's way is cleared now and rook now attacking from E1 square.

this is one illustration of Discovered check many other possibilities could happen in game.

You could play with me on Chess.com my username is hasanbadshah :)

remember two rooks can never create a discovered check.
but queen+rook can create it would be like of rook move and check, which result cleared the queen's way which also threatening the enemy king so it is discovered.
If any confusion u have feel free to post.

Comment: This is somewhat relevant, but it is *not* an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: There is no discovered check in this position so this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: I was just trying to make him clear what is discovered check and what are possible simple ways to have it in daily games. I have experience of more than 15 years in chess what about u people?